# setting up static ip

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, network-interface

I tried setting up a static ip on my ubuntu 16.04 system using this [guide](https://michael.mckinnon.id.au/2016/05/05/configuring-ubuntu-16-04-static-ip-address/)

so I bought a network card since my motherboard's ethernet port is broken but when i enter  **sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces** to input the new info, the card doesn't show up althought it does when I enter **ifconfig**. As you can see the card is connected to the internet and working properly;[image]

I also tried inputting the ports to see what would happen with the desired static ip's and all, but my connection would only work for a second. Any ideas how to fix this? 
thanks!

update: I was unable to set a static ip with my router because of some dns issue, so i hooked my pc up directly to the modem (which is also a router) and using what @G_G posted i was able to set my desired ip

Comment: Did you restart the network service after inputting the static ip information? Also, can you show the information that you put in their itself?

Comment: # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    auto lo enp1s0f0 enp1s0f1
    iface lo inet loopback
    iface enp1s0f0 inet static
   address 10.0.0.150
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 10.0.0.255
    iface enp1s0f1 inet static
   address 10.0.0.150
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 10.0.0.255

    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

Comment: i only restarted my router but not my modem, not sure if i should've done both @NasirRiley sorry if the layout of the last comment is messy, i can't figure out how to make it pretty.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the card does not have to show up under /etc/network/interfaces, you can just enter it manually. 
Once the boot process sees a 1:1 match between a name in your interfaces file, and an actual interface, it will then apply the configuration. 
Here's a very basic stanza, obviously, replace the interface's names, with your own. 
Either If down/up, or reboot.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

You can also set a static IP "on the fly" from bash, using this command, it will not however, survive a reboot.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and then add a default route

```
sudo route add default gw eth0
```

again, don't forget to swap "eth0" with the actual name of your interface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ill give it a try but i have some questions: Is the line    `iface lo inet loopback` which appears under    `auto lo eth0` important or can i remove i? Also can I assign the same ip address for 2 ports, since my network card has 2?

Comment: forgot to mention you, @G_G

Comment: Leave the loopback setup as it is, it is a logical interface used by the OS.  You can have multiple IP addresses, but only one should have the "gateway" definition, otherwise, you'll have to configure a bit more complex routing definitions.

Comment: After playing around with it, my network card shows up, with the desired ip address but no internet connection. I get a `Dns_probe_finished_no_internet` error do i have to specify a dns server? im gonna try bypassing the router, connecting it directly to the modem to see if it works

Comment: Place your DNS address in /etc/resolv.conf, e.g "name server 8.8.8.8". You can also ping 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS server), to see if you have internet, but having a DNS issue. Meaning you can reach the internet via direct IP, but having a name resolution issue.