# How can I port forward?

Tags: port-forwarding

I want to port forward some ports but I'm having some trouble understanding how to do it since it asks for a trigger port and I can't find a trigger port for the application i want to run. I also looked at the **virtual server** option but I don't understand what it does since after applying the changes the selected ports were still closed.

My system is on a static IP, and is running Ubuntu 16.04.

[image: Virtual Servers section in the router]

Comment: This is about configuring your router right? Which is presumably not running Unix/Linux?

Comment: I guess, can my computer be blocking what I'm trying to do? sorry for my lack of knowledge @Sparhawk

Comment: No worries. If it's about the router itself, it has nothing to do with Unix/Linux and is off-topic here. I'd try Superuser, perhaps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 3):

## Apart from the port forwarding

in Virtual Servers section of your router, you need to:

1. Open the port(s) in your firewall, presumably `iptables`.
2. The ports still remain closed if no application is configured and running on that port. Be sure to launch it.

---

## An example

Suppose you want to open port for your SSH on non-standard port, say 57329, then you would do:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 57329 -m comment --comment "SSH" -j ACCEPT
```

---

## Possible culprit

You also don't mention in your question if your router has a [public IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Public_address) or not. If not, it won't ever work. Sometimes you need to pay your ISP for it, sometimes not. Please verify this and clarify in your question.

As for your claim:

> My system is on a static IP, and is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Well, your computer might have static IP, but is it a [public IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Public_address)? I doubt so.

Based on your [previous effort on a static IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/442435/126755), which I see here, I highly doubt you have a [public IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Public_address) on your router.

Comment: After a bit of reading I now understand the differences between internal/external ip addresses and the advantages of a static ip. So to answer your question, no I don't have a public static ip address. Im guessing it would be impossible for me to port forward right? btw thanks for putting up with my ignorance

Comment: @paranormalbrotivity Yes, it is impossible without public static IP. I am sorry. No need to apologize. We all need to learn.

Comment: @paranormalbrotivity Please mark the answer as solved, if it helped you clarify the issue.