# Keep a static IP after restarting on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Okay, so I have a server in a location 350m away from me. It's there along with other servers needed to distribute internet to my  village and nearby villages (we're an ISP). Because the server isn't behind a router, it's directly connected to internet, it needs to have static IP. Every time I enter a static IP, the static IP goes away and I need to go to the location and manually enter it. I want to prevent this. How I can do this? (Everything goes away, broadcast address, netmask, DNS servers, etc.)

Comment: Have you read https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-10-cosmic-cuttlefish-linux?

Comment: You're telling me that no one at your "ISP" has a clue how to set a static IP adress? I'm shocked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting up static ip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442435/setting-up-static-ip)

Comment: Why you are saying it's "ISP" in quotes? Everytime I restart it it reverts back